# How to use performseguewithidentifier when a beacon is in range

Tags: xcode, swift, ibeacon

I would just like to ask how to `performseguewithidentifier` and open a new view,
 when a beacon is in range of the application.

Please help me and provide an example and documentation. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tutorials you should look at:

- [Ray Wenderlich iBeacons](https://www.raywenderlich.com/101891/ibeacons-tutorial-ios-swift)
- https://willd.me/posts/getting-started-with-ibeacon-a-swift-tutorial
- http://ibeaconmodules.us/blogs/news/14702963-tutorial-swift-based-ibeacon-app-development-with-corelocation-on-apple-ios-7-8

These links all give examples of how to use CoreLocation to figure out when your phone is in range of an iBeacon. Then, you can use the `performSegueWithIdentifier` method to open a new view controller, like so:

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segueToMyOtherVC", sender: self)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @Dze Please mark as best answer if this helped you :)